Codeigniter 4 Gateway Timeout
I have a project made on Codeigniter 4.4.8 + MySQL
The setup is:
Routes.php
$routes->get('admin_start',  'Admin::index');
$routes->get('admin_ejercicios',  'Admin::admin_ejercicios');
$routes->get('admin_rutinas',  'Admin::admin_rutinas');

Controller: Admin.php
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;
use App\Models\Admin_model;
use App\Models\Admin_users_model;

use App\Controllers\BaseController;


class Admin extends BaseController
{

    protected $helpers = ['form','url','html'];

    public function index()
    {
        $data['content_view']="admin/admin_users_view";
        return view('admin/admin_main_view',$data);
    }

    public function admin_ejercicios()
    {
        $data['content_view']="admin/admin_ejercicios_view";
        return view('admin/admin_main_view',$data);
    }

    public function admin_rutinas()
    {
        $user_id    =$this->request->getGet('id');

        $admin_model= new Admin_users_model();
        $user_name=$admin_model->get_username($user_id);

        $data['user_name']=$user_name;
        $data['user_id']=$user_id;
        $data['content_view']="admin/admin_rutinas_view";
        
        return view('admin/admin_main_view',$data);
    }
}

.htaccess
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

</IfModule>


Calling:
http://192.168.1.167/gym/admin_rutinas?id=70
or
http://192.168.1.167/gym/admin_ejercicios
or
http://192.168.1.167/gym/admin_start
I receive this error:
504 Gateway Timeout
The gateway did not receive a timely response from the upstream server or application
it takes 5 minutes -> 3000 seconds to show the error
That error doesn't always occur, but when I access this method two or three times, the error appears.
Sometimes the response time is reduced to 7 seconds instead of 5 minutes. I do not know why.
After receiving the error I refresh the page and everything works fine.
I have this error on localhost and also on my Hosting server.
So, I think it couldn't be something related to my local server/Apache configuration, because the same behavior is happening on my hosting.
The database has only a few records, so I don't think it is due to a long response from the server.
Any ideas?

it turned out to be a problem with my browser DNS cache.
ipconfig /flushdns solved the issue
